# "Erledigen" and "machen"

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between *erledigen* and *machen*? Is one more formal and the other isn't?

> Ich erledige morgen meine Einkäufe.
>
> Er macht am Abend seine Hausaufgaben.

Comment: These words aren't synonyms. One roughly means to make/do and the other to finish.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*Machen* is super generic and can be used for pretty much any situation in which something gets done. The focus is on the doing rather than on the finishing. The translation is **to make** as in **to produce**.

> Ich mach einen Kuchen.

This means that you are making a cake and that implies that you'll finish the work. It is not good style but people do use *machen* sometimes even if other verbs would be more precise and idiomatic.

*Erledigen* is much more narrow. It means **to get done** and it only works for tasks. The focus is not so much on the doing but on the finishing it and you cannot *erledigen* random objects. You can just *erledigen* tasks.

> Ich erledige die Einkäufe.

That works because *Einkauf* while being a noun, is also a task.

> Ich erledige einen Kuchen.

This doesn't work because a cake is not a task. You can *erledigen* the baking, but that's it.
So *erledigen* is a subgroup of *machen* . You can always replace it with *machen* but NOT vice versa.

I guess we should also mention that one can also *erledigen* living beings. That basically means to kill or at least to defeat.

Comment: Yes, the "Terminator" would be the "Erlediger" in proper German.

Answer (score 3):

"machen" is almost as versatile as "to do" in English. For written texts try to find more suitable words, although in conversations "machen" is quite often used.

You can hear sentences like "Ich mache Urlaub", "Ich mache Hausaufgaben", "Ich mache einen Tisch". But you should write "Ich fahre/fliege in Urlaub", "Ich erledige meine Hausaufgaben", "Ich baue einen Tisch".

So yes, one is more formal (and less versatile) than the other.

Comment: +1, however *Urlaub machen* seems to me to be a perfectly fine expression with a different meaning then *in Urlaub fahren*, while *einen Tisch machen* seems really bad, especially since *bauen* is such an easy and much better alternative.

Answer (score 2):

It is difficult, because *machen* is idiomatic in some contexts, but in other contexts it is better avoided.

Examples where you need not replace *machen*, though of course, it is almost always possible:

> Mach, daß du weiterkommst!  *Get lost!*

Possible replacement would be *Sieh zu*.

> Mußt du immer Schwierigkeiten machen? *Do you really need to make trouble all the time?*

Possible replacement would be *bereiten*.

> Das macht nichts. *It doesn't matter.*
>
> Das macht Spaß! *It's fun!*

No replacement in the preceding two examples.

> Mach hin! *Quick!*

Alternative would be *Beeil' dich!*

Comment: Good stuff, but the question seems more about contrasting "machen" and "erledigen" rather than just focusing on "machen".

Comment: @Kevin yes, but I hope my examples show that *erledigen* is a substitute for *machen* only in rare cases, like with the *Hausaufgaben*, but these were already mentioned. So it might answer the question for the difference.